# Add rows for missing data in a sequence

Tags: r, merge

I have a data frame with three columns give below:

1. A catalog code
2. Spend on that catalog code in a given week
3. The number of the week in the period

Some dummy data is below.

```
cat.code<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","d")
dol<-c(4,10,2,5,6,8,9,10)
wk.purch<-c(1,2,3,1,5,2,3,4)

fk.data<-data.frame(cat.code,dol,wk.purch)
> fk.data
  cat.code dol wk.purch
1        a   4        1
2        a  10        2
3        a   2        3
4        b   5        1
5        b   6        5
6        b   8        2
7        c   9        3
8        d  10        4
```

I want to add rows that have `dol = 0` when there is no purchase in a given week.

So, looking at `cat.code= a`, I would want to transform this data frame to add two more rows for weeks 4 and 5 that have 0 for `dol`. I have tried using `expand.grid()` and `merge` together, but that isn't working for me.

Thank you, all!

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, this works great.  I see you have the expected output below which is just what I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `merge/expand.grid`

```
 transform(merge(expand.grid(cat.code= unique(fk.data$cat.code), 
          wk.purch=unique(fk.data$wk.purch)),
        fk.data, all.x=TRUE), dol= replace(dol, is.na(dol), 0))
 #   cat.code wk.purch dol
 #1         a        1   4
 #2         a        2  10
 #3         a        3   2
 #4         a        4   0
 #5         a        5   0
 #6         b        1   5
 #7         b        2   8
 #8         b        3   0
 #9         b        4   0
 #10        b        5   6
 #11        c        1   0
 #12        c        2   0
 #13        c        3   9
 #14        c        4   0
 #15        c        5   0
 #16        d        1   0
 #17        d        2   0
 #18        d        3   0
 #19        d        4  10
 #20        d        5   0
```

Or using `data.table`, we can use a similar approach with `CJ`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(fk.data`), and set the key column as 'cat.code' and 'wk.purch'.  Join with the output of `CJ` and change the `NA` values in 'dol' to '0'.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(fk.data, key= c('cat.code', 'wk.purch'))[CJ(cat.code=unique(cat.code), 
       wk.purch=unique(wk.purch))][is.na(dol), dol:=0][]
```

Answer (score 4):

here's a tidyr solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
fk.data %>% 
  spread(cat.code, dol, fill = 0) %>% 
  gather(cat.code, dol, -wk.purch)
```

Comment: You missing a package here. Though nice solution.

Comment: which one? after assigning fk.data, I can run the code in a new session without any problem.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. AFIK `tidyr` doesn't export `%>%`, maybe the devel version does?

Comment: could be, also I agree that it's always appropriate to load dplyr together with tidyr :)

Comment: I don't know about "appropriate", it's just you need to export `%>%` somehow, either via `dplyr` or `magrittr`